# What functions are necessary to program a PHP script that can interact with an AJAX website like a normal browser?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, proxy

I want to know what is necessary to create a PHP script that can interact with a website like a normal browser. The website would be rich in Ajax, so the PHP script needs to know how to handle Javascript functions and maintain an continuous connection with the website.

Comment: OK, so after you have this, what are you going to use it more -- this may allow us to make alternate suggestions.

Comment: The script would analyze text given by the website that was generated through Javascript, and respond. For example, the website outputs a chat message in an Ajax chat form; the script analyzes it, replies with its own chat message, and awaits another chat message from the website, repeating this process until either party terminates connection.

Comment: Is this limited to a service you know, and can prepare your script for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're seeking what's called an HTTP client. PHP has one called [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). See this [example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php):

> ```
> <?php
>
> $ch = curl_init("http://www.example.com/");
> $fp = fopen("example_homepage.txt", "w");
>
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
>
> curl_exec($ch);
> curl_close($ch);
> fclose($fp);
> ?>
> ```

cURL doesn't do Javascript however. If you need to evaluate Javascript, that's a far taller order and I might suggest you look at Google's [V8 Javascript engine](http://code.google.com/p/v8/), but it's a C++ project.

Comment: Even though cURL is great, it doesn't do JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for would amount to creating a full-fledged browser, complete with Javascript interpreter, in PHP. That is never, ever going to happen. You will have to split whatever you want to achieve into parts, and try to implement those in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

If this is for testing purposes only you should maybe take a look at [Selenium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_(software)).